# How do you quickly transfer a link from your computer to an Android smart phone?

Tags: android, transfer, smartphone

I need a way to transfer links quickly in order to open them from my Android smartphone.

Any ideas?

Note it's not about files, It's just links and I'm looking for a manner to do it properly, easily and quickly.

It could be preferably through internet. But other possibilities would be through: phone network, bluetooth, LAN (wi-fi) or QR code.

Comment: Please edit your question to reflect the version of ubuntu you are using. Also give details about what connectivity you have between your phone and the computer, eg. wireless, bluetooth, wired, etc.

Comment: You could also use QR codes.

Comment: I've added some ways to connect both devices, but I'm looking for the more flexible solution, so that It should be through internet.
I don't consider relevant my ubuntu version, since it probably can change the next week and I'm looking for a ubuntu universal solution.

Comment: @saiarcot895 any easily QR codes generator for the computer out there?

Comment: In Ubuntu, see the packages qrencode (command-line), qreator (has a GUI, I think), and qtqr (uses Qt, has GUI).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome to Phone is the official (Google) way to do it.

[Browser Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-chrome-to-phone-ex/oadboiipflhobonjjffjbfekfjcgkhco)
[Android App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.chrometophone)

Comment: I took time to accept this answer because I was checking that everything is working fine. And it is!!

First of all, I had problems to install the android app, so I've installed the apk file I found in internet.

Second, and confirmed it's working on google chrome, I found out how to get it working in firefox. The answer is as simple as to install fox to phone addon: [link](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/foxtophone/)

Thanks and I hope this helps

Comment: By the way, for those who are wondering how to do the other way around, this is, from phone to firefox. You use firefox browser from the phone, press options buttons, go to share and selecet firefox sync, then select one device which is on your firefox sync account to send the tab to.
You could use the same mechanism from the computer (using ff sync) by using [send tab to device addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/send-tab-to-device/)

Comment: Neither of these links work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I've created the following bookmarklet for my Firefox bookmarks toolbar, it uses Google APIs to create a bookmarklet (for simplicity):

> `javascript:(function(){var i=new Image,p=i.src=prompt("Data",location.href);if(!p)return;i.title=p;i.src="https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=300x300&chl="+encodeURIComponent(p);i.style.cssText="position:fixed;top:50%;left:50%;margin-left:-160px;margin-top:-160px;border:20px solid #ccc;z-index:9999";i.addEventListener("click",function(){this.parentNode.removeChild(this)});document.body.appendChild(i)})()`

When activated, it will prompt you to enter data (by default the URL of the current page). Press OK to get a QR code displayed on the current page <sup>1</sup>. When done, press the QR picture to make it go away.

In order to add it (assuming you have a bookmarks toolbar):

1. Right-click the bookmarks toolbar, select *New bookmark*.
2. At *Name*, enter `QR` (or whatever identifier you would like).
3. At *Location*, paste the above script. Note that spaces will be converted to `%20` on pressing OK, this is normal (URL encoding).
4. Press OK to save (optionally enter a description mentioning this page in case there is an update).

On your Android phone, install the Barcode Scanner app (beware for malicious clones in the Play Store).

- [Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.zxing.client.android) (Google's "store")
- [F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdfilter=barcode&fdid=com.google.zxing.client.android) (OSS repository)

<sup>1</sup> It will not work for websites that define a restricted Content Security Policy (for example, Github). Askubuntu works fine though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **KDE Connect** on your phone and **GSConnect** in ubuntu.

This will allow to send link from your phone to ubuntu and much much more than that, if you are interested in that.

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1319/gsconnect/

https://f-droid.org/packages/org.kde.kdeconnect_tp/ or
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.kde.kdeconnect_tp

https://askubuntu.com/a/1036352/350004

Comment: I'm not using GNOME Shell. I'm using Unity.