# No LAN connectivity

Tags: samba, 18.10

I'm currently running Ubuntu 18.10. I recently tried installing GSConnect , but my phone couldn't see the computer. Tried adding the IP address in the app, but no go there either.

In addition, I've not been able to get Samba to work, either as client or server. Being rather an amateur dabbler in Ubuntu, I'm not sure, but given that neither is working, I'm wondering if it's a larger problem than solely GSConnect .

Comment: is there a firewall running on Ubuntu?

Comment: Only ufw. But would that prevent me using Ubuntu as a Samba client?

Comment: Usually not, but you should chek the current configuration. What are the services allowed?

Comment: How do I check them exactly? Sorry, I'm a real beginner with Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**How to check the configuration of Ubuntu Firewall**

Open a terminal, and hit:

```
sudo ufw status
```

You will get something like:

```
Firewall loaded

To                         Action  From
--                         ------  ----
22:tcp                     DENY    192.168.0.1
22:udp                     DENY    192.168.0.1
22:tcp                     DENY    192.168.0.7
22:udp                     DENY    192.168.0.7
22:tcp                     ALLOW   192.168.0.0/24
22:udp                     ALLOW   192.168.0.0/24
```

**How to view details about details defined for Samba**

```
sudo ufw app info Samba
```

**How to enable Samba if not yet enabled**

```
sudo ufw allow Samba
```

Comment: Thanks! Turns out Samba wasn't in the firewall, following your steps helped. But I still can't add see windows devices from files>other locations>windows network. Any clue what could cause this? I'm looking for a windows 7 computer.

I found a solution solution as regards GSConnect (From https://askubuntu.com/questions/1036351/how-to-install-and-run-gsconnect-to-have-android-integration-fransfer-files-se):

 sudo ufw allow 1714:1764/udp
sudo ufw allow 1714:1764/tcp
sudo ufw reload

Comment: Update: I changed the client max protocol as described at https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2384959. Now the windows PC is appearing in files, but when I click on it, I get a message with the title "unable to access location" and subtitle "failed to retrieve share list from server: connecting refused "

Comment: For first, you should check that there are shared folders on the windows pc. Next, try disabling the windows firewall for a test.

Comment: There are definitely shared folders on windows. And I can access them with ES File Explorer on Android. So the firewall on Windows probably isn't the problem, but I tried disabling it anyway, still no luck. I Googled and found that Win 7 understands upto SMB2, so I edited smb.conf to include `max protocol = SMB2` and `client max protocol = SMB2`. Now when I go to Files>Other Locations, the Windows PC isn't appearing. When I click on Windows Network, I get "Folder is Empty". Yet Ubuntu share is accessible from both Windows and Android.

Comment: Update: Followed instructions suggested at https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1169149. After trying remedies for Problem 3, I managed to access the Windows share from Ubuntu by going to "Other Locations", then typing smb://<IP Address> at the bottom and clicking connect. Original question therefore solved, although the Nautilus interface is still not displaying the Windows PC in "Other Locations".