# KDEConnect & Oppa A5 can't detect one another

Tags: networking

Tried to use this KDEConnect on Linux Mint yesterday. No joy. This morning I installed Ubuntu thinking it may have more luck. But no connection.
What I've tried:

- Turned off 5ghz band on router cuz phone & linux box was on different bands.
- tried manually connecting to Ubuntu from phone by inputting ip address.
- tried GSConnect, still no connection
- used gufw to allow KDE Connect to pass through

I'm using a BT Home Hub 2.

None of this has worked. I'm getting the feeling that KDEConnect is perhaps no longer functional, is this true? Or is there a step I'm missing. Much appreciate any help anyone can offer, I'm only using Linux a few months so any help should be dumbed down.

Comment: GSConnect is a GNOME Shell Extension. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1036351/how-to-install-and-run-gsconnect-to-have-android-integration-fransfer-files-se

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately that hasn't worked, neither device sees one another.

Comment: Hi, do you know of a version of Linux that is compatible with KDEConnect?

Comment: Only Ubuntu and *flavors* (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) of Ubuntu are on-topic here, so if it works in one, it should work in all of that release. You weren't specific as to release version, and whilst I don't use KDEConnect, I am aware of a lot of people who love it & use it reliably. Release details help narrow down issues, and you provided none.  This isn't a Linux support site, but a Ubuntu one.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I'll go elsewhere.